# It seems possible to reassign const in Next JS React component without TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, next.js, constants

When running below snippet of code:

Expected: Browser doesn't alert at all and TypeError is logged to console when reassign const.
Actual: Browser manages to run the code without Error and console.log(num) works fine.

Chrome Version 104.0.5112.101 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Edge Version 104.0.1293.63 (Official build) (64-bit)
Environment: VS Code 1.70.2

I only get experience this behaviour when running React in Next JS apps. Vanilla Javascript files work as expected.

```
const Component = () => {


  function reassign() {

    const num = 44;
    num = 77;

    //line below logs 77
    console.log(num);
  }


  return (
    <button onClick={reassign}>Shouldn't log 77 when clicking this button</button>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

Comment: Is your code being transpiled to ES5? const/let did not exist in pre-ES6 JavaScript, and many babel configs will target ES5 for compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: @ChrisB. thanks for replying - will investigate that further. I don't know if it is somehow. I used the standard npm install next react react-dom to create the project. I'm not sure if I needed to add any additional config to make my code ES6 compatible, haven't been able to find any info about this online.